# Use flash var grabbed by another function JS

Tags: javascript, flashvars

so this is what I need to do. So this function is called when the Flash video recorder on the page saves the video:

```
function onSaveOk(streamName,streamDuration,userId,cameraName,micName,recorderId){
        //alert("onSaveOk("+streamName+","+streamDuration+","+userId+","+cameraName+","+micName+")");

        //the user pressed the [save] button inside the recorder and the save_video_to_db.XXX script returned save=ok
        //recorderId: the recorderId sent via flash vars, to be used when there are many recorders on the same web page
            $('#record').hide();
            $('#jwplayer').show();

    }
```

I then have my JWplayer script that I would like to use the streamName flash var. Here is my JWPlayer script with my current attempt:

```
<div id="jwplayer">
<center>
<div id='mediaplayer'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player.swf',
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '580',
    'provider': 'rtmp',
    'streamer': 'rtmp://domain/recorder/_definst_',
    'file': 'onSaveOk("+streamName+")'
  });
</script>
</center>
```

This is where I try to use the flash var,

```
'file': 'onSaveOk("+streamName+")'
```

As it is like that, it does not work, could someone show me the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You forgot some quotes... `'file': 'onSaveOk("'+streamName+'")'`.

Comment: @Aletheios When i do that, the jwplayer doesnt show up at all.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but I guess you'll have to re-initialize the jwplayer as soon as the value of `streamName` is known (make sure that the variable exists (= is defined) and contains a useful value).

Comment: @Aletheios How would I re initialize it? EDIT: Oh, just saw  (make sure that the variable exists (= is defined) How would I do that?

Comment: How to re-initialize: If that's supported, you'll find a hint in the documentation. Else remove the `div#mediaplayer` from the DOM, then add it again and re-init the player. How to check if the variable exists: You could simply try a `console.log(streamName)` before initializing the jwplayer. If it's undefined, try to figure out the execution order of your script (what functions are called when, where are the variables defined etc.). I can't give you more accurate advice as I don't have your code...

Comment: @Aletheios Wait could I have a function just like this? function `jwPlayer(){  jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player.swf',
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '580',
    'provider': 'rtmp',
    'streamer': 'rtmp://domain/recorder/_definst_',
    'file': 'onSaveOk("+streamName+")'
  });
}` And would it show the player?

Comment: Well, why not? If it's called at the right moment, it should show the player. I reread you question now; I guess you're trying to show the video when `onSaveOk` is called/triggered? If so, just call your new `jwPlayer()` function from within `onSaveOk` and pass `streamName` as a parameter. In the player setup, you could then use `'file': streamName`. But again, I can only guess...

Comment: @Aletheios I created this function with a temp flv file <script type="text/javascript">
`function jwPlayer(){
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup(
{ 'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player.swf', 'id': 'playerID', 'width': '640', 'height': '580', 'provider': 'rtmp', 'streamer': 'rtmp://domain/recorder/_definst_', 'file': 'dog.flv' });
}
</script>` In onSaveOk I try to call it like this and it doesnt show up: jwPlayer();

Comment: Hmm there are so many errors that can occur in a script like that, it's almost impossible for me to guess the cause... I'd recommend you work with Firebug (if you don't already use it), it's a great tool that helps you debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

This site makes understanding and implementing a flash var as no-brainer as it gets.
Copy and paste code:

http://www.justthecodeplease.com/category/urls-flashvars/